# Warning: App must target Android 13 (API level 33) or higher

Tags: progressive-web-apps, google-play-console

Currently, I have a PWA setup and got the message on Google Play Console.
Warning: App must target Android 13 (API level 33) or higher.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHd4s.png)

Upon clicking on **View affected app bundles**, this is what I get:

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EObzI.png)

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to tackle this? thanks.

I am not sure how to handle this, PWAs are supposed to run on browsers, why there is a compatibility issue with Android OS?

Answer (score 0):

Pause the internal testing track will do

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).